# nodemailer refresh access token

Tags: web-deployment

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({

    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      type: 'oauth2',
      user: 'jeannywcs@gmail.com',
      clientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      clientSecret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      refreshToken: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      accessToken: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Hello everyone, I have a problem of deployment form contact with nodemailer, my Oauth seems pretty good but my refresh-token does not refresh my access token that has only one hour of validity of this fact my form only works well during this time or until you manually change the access tok